# Windows Azure - Table Services - Under the Hood

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage

When you use the Table Services API in Windows Azure what is really doing under the hood? I think I read somewhere that this is not using SQL Server. Is it doing a hash table and then filters are really running like map/reduce actions? I'm really new to this stuff and I'm curious to what it is really doing.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's speculation about service implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure Table Storage uses the EAV model.  The [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity-attribute-value_model) has more information.

The TableStorage examples map to REST calls using ADO.NET Data Services.

Comment: Any good links to describe what you are talking about? I understand the EAV thing. But how does table storage abstract this away from you?

Answer (score 2):

An excellent research paper has been published by the Windows Azure Storage (WAS) team in 2011 at the 23rd ACM Symposium on Operating Systems Principles (SOSP) about the underlying software architecture of the WAS.

You can find it [here](http://sigops.org/sosp/sosp11/current/2011-Cascais/printable/11-calder.pdf).

This paper provides in-depth technical insights of the WAS implementation.

To sum-it-up, both Table and Blob Storage do not rely on SQL. They are both Key-Value pair No-SQL storages designed to provide large scalability at the price of lower atomicity guarantees.

Initially, the Table storage was more or less marketed as if it could be used as a relationnal storage like SQL, but it does not. It is very much like the BlobStorage. The main difference between Blob and Table (in addition to the pricing of reads and writes) is that you cannot achieve any transaction implying multiple Blobs in an atomic way in the BlobStorage, while you can achieve transactions implying multiple entities (up to 100) in an atomic way in the TableStorage (provided these entities belong to the same Table and share the same partition key).